# string to integer in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to convert a string to integer with the function below but it returns the message 
TypeError: pos.replace is not a function

```
var pos=1.904;
pos = pos.replace(".", "");
pos = Number(pos);
```

Comment: what would replacing a dot with the empty string inside a number do? It's not a string...

Comment: @ShaunakD assuming you mean `parseInt`, that turns a string into a number. He already has a number.

Comment: I thought OP just wants to convert float to integer.

Comment: @ShaunakD in which case I'd suggest `Math.round(pos)`

Comment: Yeah, that's right in that case.

Comment: @JanDvorak OP wants a output like `1904` not `1`.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy that's why I said "in which case I would"

Comment: I am guessing you might be in a country that delimits 1000s with periods and not commas? The title was misleading as you are not actually converting a string to an integer. You are either `a)` converting a decimal value to an integer by multiplying by 1000, or `b)` removing formatting from an input number, in which case you should do that where it is input *before it becomes a number*. I would like to know where your values come from as that changes the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

That error message is appearing because you are invoking `.replace()` a native `string` method over a `number`. Use `.toString()` to convert the number to string, and then invoke the `.replace()` method over that.

Try,

```
var pos=1.904;
pos = pos.toString().replace(".", "");
pos = Number(pos);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e8kD6/)

Answer (score 2):

Your declaration is not a string so it's causing error. Put the value within quote.

```
var pos="1.904";
```

Comment: I think we can assume the number comes from a number initially, and not from a hard-wired value. Otherwise he might as well write `1904` to begin with :)

Comment: if so, he needs to use toString() as @Rajaprabhu, I also have the definition like that but seeing his answer I deleted that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Adding empty string to convert number into string .then you have to use `replace method`

```
var pos=1.904+"";
pos = pos.replace(".", "");
alert(+pos);
```

OR try with different solution it will be rounded everything if you have 3 digits you have to multiply by 1000 or do like this way .it is some different from others

```
var pos=10090.4+"";//199,1.904, 1.02,1.0000058,1555.02,16888.1582 what ever 
var len=pos.split(".");
if(len[1]){
   pos=pos* Math.pow(10,len[1].length);
}

alert(pos);
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J4V5C/14/)

Answer (score 1):

`var pos=1.904;` is not string.
thats the reason `.replace` not work with it.

use

```
var pos="1.904";
pos = pos.replace(".", "");
pos = Number(pos);
```